# Comparison at the condition numbers of the matrices

Tags: matrices, condition-number

We have the matrix $M_1=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ and its condition numbers are $\text{cond}_1=\|M_1\|_1\|M_1^{-1}\|_1=4\cdot 2=8$ and $\text{cond}_\infty=\|M_1\|_\infty\|M_1^{-1}\|_\infty=4\cdot 2=8$ .

We also have the matrix $M_2=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ and its condition numbers are $\text{cond}_1=\|M_2\|_1\|M_2^{-1}\|_1=4\cdot \frac{9}{2}=18$ and $\text{cond}_\infty=\|M_2\|_\infty\|M_2^{-1}\|_\infty=5\cdot 5=25$ .

We have to compare these conditions numbers to each other.

What exactly do we have to say?

At the first example we get the same condition number for both norms because the matrix is symmetrix, but at the second matrix we get different numbers since the matrix si not symmetric.

Is this the comparison that we have to say? Or what exactly do we have to compare?

Comment: Perhaps we can mention what a condition number is, which is how much the output value of a function can change for a small change in the input argument. By changing a 1 to a 2 and making the matrix asymetric, the condition number became about 3 times worse.

Comment: So we compare the two $1$-condition number and the two $\infty$-condition number, right? @KlaasvanAarsen

Comment: I'm not really sure what the difference is for using different p-norms. I can only observe that in this case the 1-norm is lower than the $\infty$-norm in both cases, which implies that the 1-norm gives a sharper bound.

Comment: If we compare $M_1$ and $M_2$, I think we should use the same p-norm to compare them. For the 1-norm we see that $\operatorname{cond}_1(M_2)$ is $18/8$ times worse. And for the $\infty$-norm we see that it is $25/8$ times worse.